# Looping logic on JSON

Tags: php, json, loops

I'm at a logical roadblock on how to implement something I'm doing. I'm working with the Instagram API(not important to this question) and in their JSON response they give you 20 results and a link to the next 20 results. I'm trying to build an OOP library that can get the response from the initial API call, search if it has a "next_url" value, and if it does, get the next 20 responses and so un until there's no longer an next URL. I can't quite gather the logic on how to do this...

currently here's the code to get the the first 20...

```
function __apiCall($url, $post_parameters = FALSE) {

        $curl_session = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        if($post_parameters !== FALSE) {
            curl_setopt ($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_parameters);
        }

        // Return the curl results to a variable
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->codeigniter_instance->config->item('instagram_ssl_verify'));

        $contents = curl_exec ($curl_session);

        curl_close ($curl_session);

        $return = json_decode($contents);
        return $return;


    }
```

and here's a snippet from the JSON response....

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [pagination] => stdClass Object
        (
            [next_url] => https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/3937885/media/recent?min_timestamp=&min_id=&max_timestamp=&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx49414762bea69258210d8872&max_id=133226850290424667_21341717
            [next_max_id] => 133226850290424667_21341717
        )

    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 200
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [type] => image
                    [location] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [latitude] => 39.95022
                            [name] => Neiman Group
                            [longitude] => -75.168322
                            [id] => 3937885
                        )

                    [comments] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                            [data] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )
```

Comment: "I'm trying to build an OOP library" Where is the OOP? :)

Comment: well it would be useless for me to paste it all here, I'm actually working off an existing library

Comment: What does `post_parameters` contain. Do you also need it in the further call?

Comment: most of the function is irrelevant, I just wanted to show it all to avoid a "where's the rest of it response". I'm really stuck on how to take the first response, which contains a link to the second response and create an automated process to grab everything...

Comment: Lemme write an answer. 1 sec plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getResults($url)
{
    $gotAllResults = false;
    $results = array();

    while(!$gotAllResults) {
        $result = $this->__apiCall($url);
        $results[] = $result;

        if (!property_exist($result->pagination, 'next_url') {
            $gotAllResults = true;
        } else {
            $url = $result->pagination->next_url;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

function __apiCall($url)
{
        // settings for cURL

        $contents = curl_exec($curl_session);

        curl_close ($curl_session);

        $result = json_decode($contents);
        return $return;
}
```

BTW. Why are you using two underscores in the name of your `__apiCall` function. That makes me think something [magical](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) is happening.

Comment: Dude awesome, Thanks, there were a few typos that I fixed but you the man... I'll answer with my final...

Comment: @GThompson Glad I could help and sorry about the typos. Wouldn't be much fun if it would just work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function __apiCall($url, $post_parameters = FALSE) {

        // Initialize the cURL session
        $curl_session = curl_init();

        // Set the URL of api call
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        // If there are post fields add them to the call
        if($post_parameters !== FALSE) {
            curl_setopt ($curl_session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_parameters);
        }

        // Return the curl results to a variable
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // There was issues with some servers not being able to retrieve the data through https
        // The config variable is set to TRUE by default. If you have this problem set the config variable to FALSE
        // See https://github.com/ianckc/CodeIgniter-Instagram-Library/issues/5 for a discussion on this
        curl_setopt($curl_session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $this->codeigniter_instance->config->item('instagram_ssl_verify'));

        // Execute the cURL session
        $contents = curl_exec ($curl_session);

        // Close cURL session
        curl_close ($curl_session);

        // Return the response
        return  json_decode($contents);


    }

    function getResults($url){

        $gotAllResults = false;
        $results = array();

        while(!$gotAllResults) {
        $result = $this->__apiCall($url);
        $results[] = $result;

        if (!property_exists($result->pagination, 'next_url')) {
            $gotAllResults = true;
        } else {
            $url = $result->pagination->next_url;
        }
    }

    return $results;

    }
```